# Sorting: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: python, pandas

The code is written in python 3.4 but I want to run it on python 3.7. I am using the Jupyter notebook to run. Can I create an environment in Jupyter and run the code in an older version of pandas(e.g. 0.16)?

```
--> 210             tmpvals[n] = find_non_overlapping_sample(
    211                 df.sort_index(key, ascending=phase).head(600).index, prd = no_overlap_prd)        
    212 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   3079             if name in self._info_axis:
   3080                 return self[name]
-> 3081             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   3082 
   3083     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort' `
```

Even I change the `sort` to `sort_index` or `sort_values`. The error still exists.

Here's the function(the original code).

```
def gen_keydates(df, key, seasonalData=False, no_overlap_prd = 365, chatty=True):

    tmpvals={}
    if seasonalData: # For DJF data use modified function
        for n, phase in enumerate([False, True]): # Maximum, Minimum Phase
            tmpvals[n] = findNonOverlappingSeasonSample(
                df.sort(key, ascending=phase).head(600).index, key=key)
    else:
        for n, phase in enumerate([False, True]): # Maximum, Minimum Phase
            tmpvals[n] = find_non_overlapping_sample(
                df.sort(key, ascending=phase).head(600).index, prd = no_overlap_prd)        
    compPhase ={}
    compPhase['max'] = tmpvals[0][0:11].order()
    compPhase['min'] = tmpvals[1][0:11].order()
    if chatty:
        print("Average for max/min sample of {0}: {1:2.3f} and {2:2.3f}".format(
            key,np.mean(df[key][compPhase['max']]),
            np.mean(df[key][compPhase['min']])))
    return compPhase`
```

Comment: What is your pandas version here?

Comment: Probably the newest version, I run it on Jupyter.  Is it possible to downgrade pandas to an older version on jupyter?

Comment: `sort` is deprecated, you should be using `sort_values` but you need to post code and a full description of your environment i.e. all library versions

Comment: @wongdavid It would be helpful if you could post the full error traceback here as well as `pd.__version__`.

Comment: _Even I change the sort to sort_index or sort_values. The error still exists._ are you sure you replaced all `sort` methods ? (in `if` statement AND `else` one)?

Comment: @BradSolomon It's '0.18.1'

Comment: @Arount yes, I did. The code above is the original code, I tried change it to sort_index or sort_values

Comment: @wongdavid your traceback pretty clearly says that you still have just `sort` somewhere in your code.  It's difficult for anyone to help you further because you only posted 2 lines of traceback.

Comment: @BradSolomon Here's the results I wanted to reproduce. https://github.com/benlaken/European_wind/blob/master/HBGWL_functions.py

Answer (score 2):

Sort method has been deprecated.
You should go for df.sort_values() or df.sort_index() methods.